# cypress invoke('removeAttr', 'target') not working

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

This is my cypress code:

```
 cy.get(`${sitestovisit.searchBoxFormID} > form`)
   .should('have.attr', 'target')<br>
   .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
```

`sitestovisit.searchBoxFormId` contains data from JSON and its working properly but it shows that there is a target attribute in form, but when I tried to remove it, it is not working.

and when i replace above code with:

```
 cy.get('#booking_search > form')
  .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
```

it works fine, what's the problem? i can't use directly cause I need it in loop
[Here's the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iyKV.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is failing because you have this assertion `.should('have.attr', 'target')` before this invocation  `.invoke('removeAttr', 'target')`.

The `.should('have.attr', 'target')` changes the subject from the element to the attribute, but `.invoke('removeAttr', 'target')` requires the subject to be the element in order to work.

this will work

```
 cy.get(`${sitestovisit.searchBoxFormID} > form`)
   .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
```

And.. if you need to see if the target attribute exist before deleting it I would do this.

```
  cy
      .get(`${sitestovisit.searchBoxFormID} > form`)
      .should('have.attr', 'target')

  cy
       .get(`${sitestovisit.searchBoxFormID} > form`)
       .invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
```

Answer (score 1):

I´ll would use a then statement on the element yield by cy.get:

```
cy.get(`${sitestovisit.searchBoxFormID} > form`)
  .then( $elem => {
    $elem[0].removeAttribute('target');
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this solution in [Github thread](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25330#issuecomment-1372801430). It should be added before you click the link.

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  const orig = win.open

  win.open = function (url, target, features) {
    return orig.call(this, url, '_self', features)
  }
})
```