# Can't open a link at the same tab using Cypress

Tags: javascript, html, automation, cypress

I'm trying to open a link in the same tab using cypress

I tired using

```
cy.get('a').eq(0).invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

but it didn't work. after checking the HTML file I saw that there is no

```
target=_blank
```

att on the href

I cant understand why its opening on a new window and how to prevent it using cypress.

Comment: I think its using the window.open method using JS although I'm not sure

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the `target` attribute you have to use the invoke command `removeAttr` i.e.

```
cy.get('a').invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
```

(I saw a previous answer that stated you should use "removeAttribute" but that command doesn't exist in Cypress)

More information at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838983/7949930

Answer (score -1):

For a `target=_blank` anchor,  you can either remove the `target` attribute or replace the `_blank` value with `_self`.

```js
// remove attribute target
cy.get('a')
  .eq(0)
  .should('have.attr', 'target') // check it has target attr before removing
  .invoke('removeAttribute', 'target')
  .click()

// update target value
cy.get('a')
  .eq(0)
  .should('have.attr', 'target', '_blank') // check target attr has _blank
  .invoke('attr', 'target', '_self')
  .click()
```